# Get DOMAIN for TCP Kubernetes Server behind NGINX Ingress

Tags: go, nginx, ssl, kubernetes, subdomain

I have a server that uses a custom TCP protocol. It is accessed through a subdomain such as `sub1.mydomain.com` and the server needs to know what subdomain is being used to access it.
Given the following infrastructure, how could you determine the domain and subdomain name from inside the running Kubernetes Pod?

[AWS Classic Load Balancer] ->

[Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller] ->

[Kubernetes Service] ->

[Kubernetes Deployment]

Comment: You can't for a plain TCP service. For http, this info usually comes from the `Host` header. For just TCP, domain resolution happens on the client side and is not sent to the server.

Comment: Just accepted it can't be done.